# How to detect if the call is made through jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I use

`$.post('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);});`

to send data and retrieve information and show it to the user. But "hackers" can access my file (test.php) just typing it in URL. Is it possible to detect if the call is made from jQuery or not?

Comment: "hackers" could also type `javascript: $.post('ajax/test.php', function(data) { console.log( data ); });` into the URL bar or put a break point in your script from the browser and get the data.

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer: Well, that's obvious... :)

Comment: Just saying that the check for jQuery is exploitable. You should use user authentication if you 
want to protect the data.

Comment: I see your `javascript: ...` and raise it with `telnet hey.com 80 | POST ajax/test.php HTTP/1.1 | Host: hey.com | X-Requested-With: jQuery`

Comment: @hey - If it's obvious then don't you already know the answer to your question? It seems to me your real question isn't "Is the call made from jQuery?", but "How do I tell if the request came from _my_ page?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect if the call is made from jQuery or not?

Yes, but the same "hackers" can as easily fake a jQuery call. There is no reliable way to detect whether a call was made from jQuery, or using other means. *Anybody* can make a request to a resource.

If you have sensitive data on the web, you need to protect it using classical means like a user login, HTTP basic auth, or IP limitations - just like a normal web page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the referrer on the server side. If not from your host, reject.